# Logstash grok filter doesn't work for the last field

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

With Logstash 2.3.3, grok filter doesn't work for the last field.

To reproduce the problem, create `test.conf` as follows:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/izeye/Applications/logstash-2.3.3/test.log"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{DATA:id1},%{DATA:id2},%{DATA:id3},%{DATA:id4},%{DATA:id5}" }
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Run `./bin/logstash -f test.conf`

and after it started, in another terminal run `echo "1,2,3,4,5" >> test.log`

and I got the following output:

```
Johnnyui-MacBook-Pro:logstash-2.3.3 izeye$ ./bin/logstash -f test.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
{
       "message" => "1,2,3,4,5",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-07T07:57:42.830Z",
          "path" => "/Users/izeye/Applications/logstash-2.3.3/test.log",
          "host" => "Johnnyui-MacBook-Pro.local",
           "id1" => "1",
           "id2" => "2",
           "id3" => "3",
           "id4" => "4"
}
```

You can see the missing `id5`.

I'm not sure this is a bug or mis-configured.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because how the `DATA` pattern is defined. Its regex is `.*?`, so it's a lazy match.
It's not a bug, it's how regex works ([example](https://regex101.com/r/pO2xN6/2)).
But you might want to ask a regex question in order to have an accurate answer.

As a solution, you can replace the last `DATA` with `NUMBER` (or something appropriate to your situation). `GREEDYDATA` would also work.

---

Though, in that solution, the [csv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) or [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) filters might be better fit, as easier to configure and more performant.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't check its value: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns